# Problem involving finite sets condition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I stumbled upon this innocent looking problem in my old high school algebra textbook and I just can't figure it out . It goes like this :

---

How many finite, non-empty sets satisfy the following property ?

If $x \in S$ then $2^x-1 \in S$ ($x \in \Re$).

---

Maybe it's because I'm a bit rusty, I haven't done any math in quite some time. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Ilham: But then $2^x - 1$ is in $S$, and so...

Comment: @MikeMiller  Oh okay!

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be such a set. Let $a=\max S$ and assume $a>1$. Then $2^a-1>a$ gives us a contradiction.

Assume $S\cap (0,1)$ is nonempty and let $c=\min (S\cap (0,1))$. But then $0<2^c-1<c$ gives us a contradiction. We conclude $S\cap(0,1)=\emptyset$.

Assume $S\cap (-\infty,0)$ is nonempty and let $b=\max (S\cap (-\infty,0))$. But then $b<2^b-1<0$ gives us a contradiction. We conclude $S\cap(-\infty,0)=\emptyset$.

In summary, $S\subseteq \{0,1\}$ and indeed all nonemptty subsets of $\{0,1\}$ work. So the only such sets are
$$ \{0\}\qquad\{1\}\qquad\{0,1\}$$

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, so I will post as an answer. There are at least three such sets. You'll notice that $2^1-1=1$, so that $S=\{1\}$ and $\{0,1\}$ are also sets satisfying the requirement.

Edit: I see someone wrote a response as was thinking about it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I had a mistake in my thoughts and deleted my posting consequently.